# Connecting 2-pin JST PH connector to Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino-mega, pins, connector

I’m want to connect 50 LDR to my Mega, I wondering if I use a 2-female pin JST PH connector to connect the LDR, how can I link 2-pin male JST PH connector board to the Mega and does this board exist?

Comment: Design your own.

Answer (score 0):

There exists 2.00 to 2.54mm adapters, like in [this link](https://www.gorilladistribution.com.au/product/8-pin-adapter-board-1-27mm-2-0mm-2-54mm/).

They look like below (example of 1.27, 2 and 2.54mm):

[image]